# Error When Uploading to S3 via Carrierwave and Fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

So I'm trying to use Carrierwave and Fog to upload files to Amazon S3. I first set up Carrierwave working with the local file server. Worked golden. Then I tried adding the fog gem, switching the storage to fog and adding the carrier_wave.rb initializer file and I get the error "no implicit conversion of Array into String" when I try to upload anything.

My initializer code is:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
     # Configuration for Amazon S3
     :provider              => 'AWS',
     :aws_access_key_id     => ['XXXX'],
     :aws_secret_access_key => ['XXXX']
   }
   config.fog_directory     =  ['XXXX']
end
```

And my uploader code is:

```
class MediaUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

   process :set_content_type
   process :save_content_type_and_size_in_model

  def save_content_type_and_size_in_model
    model.content_type = file.content_type if file.content_type
    model.file_size = file.size
  end

   storage :fog
```

The error seems to be stemming from the fact that carrierwave & fog is trying to pass an array into my string "media" field in my model (project). See the parameters being passed in:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXX",
 "project"=>{"name"=>"Cat",
 "description"=>"Meow meow",
 "media"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd15513f3e8 @tempfile=#    <Tempfile:/var/folders/8_/77fwkkc56r71w67p2jj5x9200000gn/T/RackMultipart20141004-77510-1k6nxyw>,
 @original_filename="SG Square.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[media]\"; filename=\"SG Square.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Create Project"}
```

Help!

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The brackets around my keys apparently were screwing with everything.

Comment: Ben, can you please elaborate what mistake you made? I am also having the same problem, but I didn't get what you tried to say in your comment

Comment: Gagan, in this case I believe I decided that it was interpreting my access key etc. as arrays due to the brackets. Once I removed the brackets it worked. Despite that I know its not the best practice, I hardcoded in my key info so that it looked like `:aws_access_key_id => 'blahblahblahblah'`. And decided to implement the setting the env variables later. Hope this helps man.